# Replacing a Oracle 11g trigger automatically enables it

Tags: database, oracle, triggers, oracle11g

A bit of software I'm working on uses triggers in Oracle. We have a whole set that are currently created and disabled in the database. When running a CREATE or REPLACE  to modify a trigger that already exists that trigger gets automatically enabled. I understand CREATE will automatically enable something but why is replace doing this?

Also what's weird however is that this only happens on one of our databases, the others are fine. Is there a setting inside the database that is causing this possibly or is enabling expected behavior of REPLACE?

Comment: I'm very surprised at your comment that "create or replace" triggers on some databases causes them to be created as disabled.

Comment: see my reply to your post below

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that the `OR REPLACE` clause is considered a modifier of the `CREATE` command rather than a command by itself. And the [CREATE TRIGGER](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7004.htm) command is designed to do so:

> Use the CREATE TRIGGER statement to create and enable a database trigger [...]
> When you create a trigger, the database enables it automatically. You can subsequently disable and enable a trigger with the DISABLE and ENABLE clause of the ALTER TRIGGER or ALTER TABLE statement.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling and disabling triggers is not a "normal" thing for an application to be doing, so you may be getting misled by this piece of software. In general if you create a piece of code that has valid syntax and can be compiled, then it's going to be enabled on creation. "create or replce" is just a convenience to be able to modify an item of code without dropping it (and possibly causing undesirable side-effects, like dropping privileges on it) first. It's no different from create in respect of compilation.

Now what you can do is "create or replace trigger ... disable when ...", which would of course create it as disabled.

Comment: Yeah understandable, its just very odd because we've run this script to replace the triggers on some databases and it doesn't turn the triggers on but others it does, do you know if there some sort of buried config setting?

Comment: Is it possible there is some sort of setting that may affect how the code is compiled? So Oracle realises its the same code and doesn't update it in its store? that would account for the trigger not being replaced and activated.

Comment: No, I can't imagine that there is. Do the disabled triggers compile OK?

Comment: yeah they compile. do you know if there's any way to do the following

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TEST AFTER DELETE ON TABLE FOR EACH ROW 
DISABLE WHEN (<STATUS OF TRIGGER IS DISABLED>)

Comment: You want the replacing trigger to inherit the enable/disable status of the current trigger? If so, then apart from reading the status prior to the create-or-replace and modifying the DDL to include DISABLE if appropriate, then sorry I don't know of a way. It's *possible* that there's something that could be done with DDL triggers, which might be able to read the current version of the trigger before the replace and modify the new trigger after the replace, possibly. All of this is a warning that the applecation is doing something very unnatural I'm afraid.

Comment: we're not really using triggers in any sort of weird way its just for auditing for some clients. 

we wrap our whole database struct in a package and it replace/creates them every time so if a user has turned them off for speed purposes they get turned back on :(. cheers for the help though man, appreciate it.

Comment: Hmmm... I'd just tell the user "you turned them off, you can turn them off again"

Comment: It could be worth looking at pl/sql conditional compilation, using a selection directive (controlled by package variables perhaps) to modify whether the triggers do anything or not. You can have the enabled but bypass their work payload based on values set elsewhere, on a trigger by trigger basis. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/fundamentals.htm#BEIGHEEC